# Visual Studio 2015 - SDK installation error (8.1.0, API 27 rev 1) Download finished with wrong size. Expected 65606517 bytes, got 65738431 bytes

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Having an issue when `trying to install the 8.1.0, API 27, revision 1 SDK`.  I get the following **error**:

> Download finished with wrong size. Expected 65606517 bytes, got 65738431 bytes.

I tried to clear the cache `(Tools -> Option -> Clear Cache)`, no worky worky.

Anyone else having issues?